# How are values being returned from those functions insiste async.parallel If they don't have a "Return" operator?

Tags: express, asynchronous

I am practicing on the LocalLibrary app exercise of Mozilla's Node/Express tutorial.

In the Express Async Module part, I can't understand how the results of each function inside the async.parallel are being retrieved, since those functions do not have a "Return" operator.

```
var Book = require('../models/book');
var Author = require('../models/author');
var Genre = require('../models/genre');
var BookInstance = require('../models/bookinstance');

var async = require('async');

exports.index = function(req, res) {

    async.parallel({
        book_count: function(callback) {
            Book.countDocuments({}, callback); // Pass an empty object as match condition to find all documents of this collection
        },
        book_instance_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        book_instance_available_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({status:'Available'}, callback);
        },
        author_count: function(callback) {
            Author.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        genre_count: function(callback) {
            Genre.countDocuments({}, callback);
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
    });
};
```

Comment: `callback` take 2 args, 1st error, 2nd data...  `countDocuments` take this callback and pass value. [a good example in doc](http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallel)

Comment: But, talking about the created functions, how does Node even know that the parameter "callback" is actually a callback function?

Comment: @Nur, the example is good. However, I still can't understand something: in your example the callback does have a result parameter ("One"). In my example, the callback has no result parameter (actually has no parameters at all), so how come it returns the result of the .countDocuments?

Comment: actually `callback` is a function, also `countDocuments` take a callback function... So you could do something like this: `Book.countDocuments({}, (err, data) => callback(err, data));`

Comment: _"how does Node even know that the parameter `callback` is actually a callback function? "_ :  Honestly you could pass any thing, If you don't pass a `callback` function, you will get a runtime error, Also JavaScript can't guaranty any argument validation (Bcs It lack static type system), So consider `Typescript` which is pure JavaScript + Optional Type system

Comment: Book.countDocuments({}, (err, data) => callback(err, data)) makes perfect sense and I'd had understood if it was written like this. The other way thoug ;(. JS wanna kill my brains.